# I cant import LDAP module in Python

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

i installed python-ldap and ldap3 :

> (einstieg) C:\Users\User\Python\modules>pip freeze

> ldap3 @file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/ldap3-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>
> pyasn1 @
> file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
>
> python-ldap @
> file:///C:/Users/User/Python/modules/python_ldap-3.4.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl

but i cant import ldap. i get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Users\Python\pyproj\einstieg\onlyscreen.py", line 5, in
>
> import ldap ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ldap'

what can i do about that?
greetings
Chorum

Answer (score 0):

What did you use to install the packages?
Where did you install the packages?
You should always install the packages in the same environment that you are running the Python script. To make your life easier, use virtual environments like Anaconda.

Maybe use `import ldap3`?

Comment: i installed the packages in an virtual environment ( thats the (einstieg) in the freeze line)
for python-ldap i used the python-ldap-3.4.0.tar and the setup.py in the VE.
i find the folder of my installations in einstieg/Lib/site-packages.
import ldap3 doesnt work :(

Comment: You should try `python -c "import ldap"` in your environment terminal. If that does not work the wrong package is installed or the import is incorrect. Mayby try with a clean environment?

Comment: Or use pip to install the packages.

Comment: with that i dont get any errors or anything else. if that is the expected correct behavior, how can i bring it to work in my code?
i cant use pip because our proxy dont let me through to pypi.python.org, pypi.org and files.pythonhosted.org
i think i have a general problem with importing modules. i tried other installed modules but everytime i get ModulNotFoundError.
i thought if i install a single module without errors and dependencies i should be able to import it.
perhaps you can help me where something went wrong? 
i will try a new venv and a single module now for a test

Comment: So i tried a new venv and the paho mqqt module. 
Installation without errors but ModulNotFoundError. 
i would like to know what i am doing wrong...

Comment: What command do you use to run your script? Did you activate you environment?

Comment: Yes i activated the venv. i use notepad ++ to run my code

Comment: It seems to be about the path to the modules. 
i have successfully imported paho now. will make some tests